# show that the theory of fields cannot be axiomatized by horn sentences

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

show that the theory of fields cannot be axiomatized by horn sentences

[image]

[image]

im not sure how to show it, nearly everything is quantified so easily no free variables, maybe something to do with $\neg0 \equiv 1$

Comment: Why not use a theorem about theories that are axiomatisable by Horn sentences? Say, the one that has something to do with products of models?

Comment: @ZhenLin im not aware of the theorem you are referring to, do you have a link?

also it seems that $\forall x(\neg x \equiv 0 \rightarrow \exists y x \cdot y \equiv 1)$ would fail in a product of two models so maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: better yet if you have a link to a proof for it, I am searching. I don't want to just quote the theorem.

Comment: I am sure such a result appears in any textbook that discusses universal Horn theories.

Comment: @oliverjones: Now you can just use your other question to solve this one!